# Why exception is thrown on caller instead of on problematic line

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, exception

I have a simple program:

```
class Program
{   
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task Run()
    {
        string someVariable = null;
        someVariable.Replace(",", ".");
    }
}
```

Run() method is intentionally designed to throw NullReferenceException. What bothers me is why exception is thrown on the line

```
Run.Wait()
```

instead of on

```
someVariable.Replace(",",".");
```

The actuall exception is available in InnerException - why is that? I lose debugging context, because exception is thrown outside of Run method.
[image]

If my program is synchronous:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();
    }

    private static void Run()
    {
        string someVariable = null;
        someVariable.Replace(",", ".");
    }
}
```

exception is thrown on the correct line. Why async breaks this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AggregateException C# example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755541/aggregateexception-c-sharp-example)

Comment: You don't "lose context". That inner exception's `StackTrace` tells you precisely where the error originated.

Comment: Instead of `Wait()` try `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, which should throw inline without the AggregateException.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call Run.Wait(), the Run() method has thrown a null exception then [Wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait_System_TimeSpan_) method will throw AggregateException. Btw you don't loss your context. If you click on [**View Details**] and view the **StackTrace** of **InnerException** of the current exception, you can found that the exception came from **Run()** method:

[image]

Comment: When I said about losing context, I meant that I cannot check content of local variables of Run method when exception throws.

Answer (score 3):

What @Nhan Phan is saying is true.

There's also another way you can deal with this issue:
Instead of using `.Wait()` you can use `.GetAwaiter.GetResult()` which will also unwrap the AggregateException.

If you are using C# 7.1 can have an `async void Main` and the `await` your `Run` method