# C# AggregateException, in what scenario would I have aggregated exceptions?

Tags: c#, aggregateexception

I am probably missing a very obvious fact, but I have a hard time understanding the need for AggregatedExceptions.

I know since async/await we don't have to bother with AggregatedExceptions anymore (or at least are confronted with them less frequently). I can relate to that, because I simply start a task and at some time I choose to synchronize the 'calling thread' with the 'task which runs in parallel'

```
var sometTask = DoSomethingInParallelAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
...
...
await someTask;
```

In this scenario, an exception that occurred in `DoSomethingInParallelAsync()` will be presented to me when I await that call.

Why is that so different *without* using `await`, but `Wait` on the `Task` explicitly?

```
var someTask = DoSomethingInParallelAsync();
...
...
someTask.Wait();
```

An exception thrown in this example, will always wrap the thrown `Exception` in an `AggregateException`. I still don't understand why.

What can't I do when using async/await which takes away the need for `AggregateException`s?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314961/i-want-await-to-throw-aggregateexception-not-just-the-first-exception

Comment: Hi @Sean, thanks for the link. Still puzzled though. In the example presented below I understand that multiple exceptions can occur on different threads / tasks in parallel. But in my question, I simply start 1 task, and wait for it. That wouldn't produce multiple exceptions on the `Task.Wait` call. So why is it still wrapped in the `AggregateException`?

Comment: Not sure if I make myself clear. I would understand that `Task.WhenAll` would throw an `AggregateException`, I don't understand why `Task.Wait` would throw an `AggregateException`

Answer (score 0):

**Causing and handling the error**

```
Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new ArgumentException(); } );
Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(); } );

try
{
    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
}
```

and also see that  [links](https://blog.elmah.io/debugging-system-aggregateexception-even-in-async-code/)

here is an example : [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26508554/10669958)

Comment: OK, that does explain why the `AggregateException` exists. But that does not really explain to me why the `Task.Wait` call would wrap the exception in a `AggregateException`. In what scenario would you be able to produce more than one exception on a single task? It's just one task, with one result, right? Failed with an exception or completed successfully. PS: I also don't understand who downvoted your answer either ...